# React Navigation Extend Header

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation in a React Native project. I am wanting to add some extra content into the header.

I have created a custom header component and am using it in a Stack navigator like so:

```
navigationOptions: {
    header: CustomHeader
}
```

This is working fine but it is obviously replacing the entire header. I know I can access the screen title with props but I don't want to have to style this so it matches screens that don't use the custom header.

Is there anyway I can use a custom header but retain the existing title? Is it possible to 'slot' content into the header after the title or include the existing title (with device styles) into the customer header?

Answer (score 2):

You can import Header component from @react-navigation/elements, and then wrap it.

Example:

```
import { Header } from '@react-navigation/elements'

function CutsomHeader(props) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Header {...props.options} />
      <SearchBar />
    </View>
  )
}
``
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `navigationOptions` inside the screens you need the `customHeader`:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
   //If you need do things
   return {
      header : <CustomHeader />
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yep I am already doing this but rather than replacing the whole header, I am wanting to slot in some extra content after the title. Otherwise I need to include the title in my customer header and make sure the height and margin etc match for IOS and Android devices.